# Is there a proper way to embeding form for related entity with Api-latform admin?

Tags: api-platform.com

is there a proper way to embeding form for related entity with Api Platform admin ? I finded 2 "hack" : using a json field intead of a relation or removing the "Replace embedded objects by their IRIs" part of this file https://github.com/api-platform/admin/blob/master/src/hydra/hydraClient.js and use it as a data provider directly with react-admin. thanks for help !

Edit:
There is a pull request that will solve this problem: [Do not alter relations when GET_ONE](https://github.com/api-platform/admin/pull/107) !

Answer (score 0):

There is a pull request that will solve this problem: [Do not alter relations when GET_ONE !](https://github.com/api-platform/admin/pull/107)